# UTF-8 character support in Rego policies/rules

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I am a newbie on OPA and Rego, evaluating OPA for one of my applications. My application support localization and multiple languages. One of them is Simple Chinese. When I tried to evaluate a simple Rego rule consisting of some simple Chinese characters, I have received an error.

Error:

```
 rego_parse_error: illegal token input.city == '米尔福德'
```

Sample rule:

```
city  := {"city" : input.city}{
      input.city == '米尔福德'
  }
```

Does Rego support UTF-8 character set, and can rules be written on values containing special characters like above?

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes does not denote a string in Rego. Using double quotes your rule works [as expected](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/qQksauwMFv).